# Rails: Calling one Model from another Model. Why is this not possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dry

I have the following Model...

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :layout
  has_many :visits

  validates :number, presence: true
  validates :rate, presence: true
  validates :smoking, presence: true

  def self.rooms_with_smoking(smoking)
    self.where('smoking = ?', smoking)
  end

  def self.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date) #24-26
    self.joins(:visits).where('date >= ? and date <= ?', from_date, to_date).uniq
  end

  def self.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date)
    self.where.not(id: Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date))
  end 

  def self.blahblah(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    layouts = Layout.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count)
    Room.rooms_with_smoking(smoking).vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(layouts)
  end
end
```

The blahblah method...

When I attempt to run this from irb I get an error... "unknown class: Layout"

1) Does Room not 'know' about Layout. Can I not use another Model like this? How can I do it.

2) Theory question: Is it better to have one large method definition to obtain some information... or is it better to have a lot of little compartmentalized methods, and use them all in one method to obtain a larger piece of data. For example...

One 'Large' Method:

```
def self.find_rooms_with(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    Room.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(:layout).where('occupancy_count >= ?', occupancy_count).where('smoking = ?', smoking)
end
```

By no means large, but everything is re-coded. Doesn't seem like it would follow DRY for long.

Many Little Methods:

```
  def self.blahblah(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    layouts = Layout.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count)
    Room.rooms_with_smoking(smoking).vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(layouts)
  end
```

The second one is easier to code. It utilizes 3 built in method definitions. However, does it have any sort of performance hit over the first one, or is it less desirable?

**EDIT**: Answering the first two comments below...

When I just type Layout, or ap Layout, I get my entire Layout model.

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base {
                 :id => :integer,
        :description => :string,
    :occupancy_count => :integer,
         :created_at => :datetime,
         :updated_at => :datetime
}
 => nil
```

And by irb, yes I mean rails console. Full Layout Model here...

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rooms

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :occupancy_count, presence: true

    def self.layouts_with_occupancy_count(occupancy_count)
        self.where('occupancy_count = ?', occupancy_count)
    end

    def self.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count)
        self.where('occupancy_count >= ?', occupancy_count)
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a Layout model? And when you say `irb` do you mean `rails console`?

Comment: yes what happens when you go to rails console and just type `Layout`

Comment: Added answers to those questions in the original post above.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The one weird thing is that production is seeing the Class i created but in development i get the no class defined error.

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems you do not declare the Layout class.

The `belongs_to` class method [expects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) a corresponding ActiveRecord class to be defined. By default it should match the method name (`:layout` corresponds to `Layout`).

Comment: So I need to have belongs_to :Layout instead of belongs_to :layout?

Comment: No, your belongs_to method call seems to be correct. And the Layout class is defined. So I'd join the derekyau question: what do you see when typing the `Layout` in a console?

Comment: I added my response in the EDIT section of the original post, but I see my Layout class. Seems to be just fine, as far as I can tell. Can I not call Room.blahblah. Do I need to join Room and Layout first, and then call .blahblah on that joined set?

Comment: @chrisP This issue does seem odd, can you confirm that you created the Layout model before entering the rails console? If not, the current process of the console will not see it without the `reload!` command.

Comment: And one more thing. Your usage of `joins` method in the `blahblah` seems odd.

You call it with an ActiveRecord::Relation `layouts` argument. 

But the API (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) assumes the string or symbol argument to be used.